# Lua opcodes in FLASH memory

Tags: lua, arm

I have a ARM CPU (SAM3S) running Lua. I have several static Librarys written in Lua. Now I run out of RAM. It is possible to move and run the Lua opcodes from RAM to FLASH? 
Thank you
AR

Comment: Is your question about the ARM side of things or the Lua side? As long as you can at least read from the flash memory at runtime you can compile the Lua scripts (the loadfile and string functions from the C api), lua_dump the compiled chunk, store it somewhere and just load it when needed.

Comment: I can use the load or loadstring function to compile Lua source to the binary form. And I can store this binary form in the FLASH memory. So far, so good! If I use load or loadstring to read in the binary form, the function copy the chunk(s) to RAM. Is this correkt? In the moment I am not shure... For Lua source it is true, but for the binary form?

Comment: Yes, the only thing to keep in mind is that `luaL_loadstring` and `luaL_loadfile` work on strings and text files, so you'll need `lua_load` when loading the binaries. The full explanation has already been provided by my favourite SO user Nicol Bolas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8936369/compile-lua-code-store-bytecode-then-load-and-execute-it

Comment: If I use the load function to read the byte code the the load function put this code on the stack.

Comment: Please ignore the commend above! If I use the load function to read the byte code the the load function put this code on the stack. Lua manual: "Loads a Lua chunk. If there are no errors, lua_load pushes the compiled chunk as a Lua function on top of the stack.". So, this eats my RAM. I looking for a way to execute a chunk at the place he is stored (in FLASH). Why it is nessesary to execute the chunk on the stack? Maybee I found a reason: CALL is limit to a distance of 131071 words, and in my CPU FLASH and RAM have mutch bigger distance. In this case the CALL must fail.

Comment: Because the chunk is a Lua function, which, like all other Lua values, is stored on the stack or in  a table.

Comment: I see. So I have to load and unload the chunk evry time I want to use it. I can do this in a wrapper function. Interesting to see how perfrmant it is. I will try. Thank you for your Help. AR

Answer (score 0):

I've written a on-demand compilation wrapper some time ago. It's hilariously easy and can be adapted to your use-case.

```
lib = setmetatable({}, {
    __mode = "v", -- important (!) allows the Lua GC to collect unused entries
    __index = function(self, k)
        -- put code here to load from FLASH
        -- in [eLua][1] this may look like:
        local chunk = loadfile("/rom/"..k..".lua")
        -- put code into the table
        self[k] = chunk;
        return chunk;
    end
})
```

Use it like this:

```
x, y, z = lib.foo(a, b, c)
```

With a bit of metatable magic, you could create a hierarchy too, and maybe collect functions into "modules" by loading all the leaves with a module.

Since your environment is very memory-constrained, I would suggest a convention over configuration approach for this as registering all available modules at load-time will surely affect memory footprint. Here is a suggestion:

```
local PATH = "/rom/src/";
local mt; mt = {
    __mode = "v",
    __index = function(self, k)
        local fn = PATH .. self.__PATH .. k .. ".lua"
        local chunk, errmsg = loadfile(fn) -- Warning Can cause security issues
        if not chunk then
            if io.open(fn) then
                chunk = setmetatable({}, mt)
                chunk.__PATH = self.__PATH .. k .. "/"
            else
                error(errmsg)
            end
        end

        self[k] = chunk;
        return chunk;
    end
}

setmetatable(_G, mt)
```

Use like this:

```
local x, y, z = a.b.c(u, v, w) -- looks for "/rom/src/a/b/c.lua
```

In both variants, the Lua GC should automatically try to collect unused code (functions with reference count `= 0`) when memory gets tight.

## More tips

- Store code as byte-code. It loads faster and (usually) takes less space on flash, which makes it load even faster yet (But is usually not compatible between versions of Lua)
- Keep variables as `local` as possible so Lua can clean up as quickly as possible
- Avoid recursion
- Avoid storing references to functions, long strings and tables in non-local variables (like `_G`)
- Avoid tables

PS: Disclaimer All code in this answer is actually written from memory and thus not tested at all.

Reference:

- [1] http://www.eluaproject.net/doc/v0.9/en_arch_romfs.html

Comment: So, I had test it on my system. I have no file system so I replaced loadfile with a new function loadFromAttic. This function use a pool of precompiled Lua chunks generated by a small command line tool.<br>
It works perfect!
Thank you, your answer was very helpfull!<br>
Andre

Comment: @andre incredible :) to help others looking for similar solutions, you can vote on answers and/or accept them. Do not accept my answer unless it was reasonably close to the solution, rather write your own answer and accept it.