# Return function as bytecode?

Tags: lua, bytecode

I would like to output a function that I've defined into bytecode. I cannot use any external libraries and only have standard API functions available to me.

My use case is that I am checking to see how likely it is that a client modified code running on his end vs. the unmodified code on my end (obviously it is impossible to know for certain).

Comment: [Here's a previous question to the same effect.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8936369/compile-lua-code-store-bytecode-then-load-and-execute-it)

Comment: @Putnam Unfortunately that question involves using C code to achieve said result. I only have access to the Lua standard library (strictly Lua code).

Comment: Just `string.dump`?

Comment: Also, there's two flaws with your idea. First, the same source code doesn't always compile into the same bytecode. If it did, then it'd be portable, but it isn't. Second, if the client can modify the code you want to look at, they can also modify the code that sends it to you, and have it send you the old code instead of the code they're really running.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I'm using Lua 5.1 and `string.dump` is `nil`. Was it renamed by chance?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica For your first point, can you illustrate an example of how a function is not deterministic in the bytecode that it becomes when ran? If you and I are running the exact same Lua interpreter and version then it should yield the same result.To address your second point, that is why I wrote the line `"(obviously it is impossible to know for certain)"`

Comment: @Hatefiend "If you and I are running the exact same Lua interpreter and version" Yes, in that case the bytecode would be the same, but unless you want to pretend that Windows is the only OS that exists, that isn't true.

Comment: Anyway, [Lua 5.1 definitely calls it `string.dump`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-string.dump), so if that's nil, it means the application that's embedding Lua removed it, so what you want is just completely impossible.